# Don't truly understood setTimeout in Discordjs

Tags: javascript, discord.js

After a minute it give me this:

[image]

I'm trying to do a russian roulette. But in the timeout the `message.reply("in setTimeout")` doesn't work, instead `console.log("in setTimeout")` did. Nvm solved with  $env:NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192":

```
  setTimeout(() => {
        message.reply("in setTimeout")
        console.log("in setTimeout");
        if (players.length < 1) return message.channel.send(`Nessuno vuole giocare? ):`);
        if (players.length < 2) return message.channel.send(`Questo è suicidio... mi piace ma non è una roulette russa da soli`);
        let scelta = sixshooter[Math.floor(Math.random() * sixshooter.length)]
        let i = 0

        while (i < players.length) {
            if (scelta == "unlucky bro ☠️") {
                players.splice(i, 1)
            }

            i++;
            if (i >= players.length) { i = 0 }
             message.channel.send(`${players[i]}, ${scelta}`)
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is standard JavaScript not just DJS. Have you tried handling the promise of `message.reply()` to see if there's anything stopping the client from sending the message?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the old space size, which defaults to 1.5GB. If you're running out of memory, there's an issue with your code.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Discord [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/Message?scrollTo=reply) `message.reply` return a promise. So call console log inside promise success callback.

```
setTimeout(() => {

        message.reply("in setTimeout").then(() => console.log("in setTimeout")))
        
        if (players.length < 1) return message.channel.send(`Nessuno vuole giocare? ):`);
        if (players.length < 2) return message.channel.send(`Questo è suicidio... mi piace ma non è una roulette russa da soli`);
        let scelta = sixshooter[Math.floor(Math.random() * sixshooter.length)]
        let i = 0

        while (i < players.length) {
            if (scelta == "unlucky bro ☠️") {
                players.splice(i, 1)
            }

            i++;
            if (i >= players.length) { i = 0 }
             message.channel.send(`${players[i]}, ${scelta}`)
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: I recommend using `.finally()` or adding `.catch()` to view any possible promise rejections. `message.reply("in setTimeout").finally(console.log)`

Comment: the problem is that nothing but console.log() works. Neither with catch or then it does somethig